# Spring Tool 4.10 having issue after install JBoss Tools - "Download Quick Start list" and "Update Project wizard list"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-tool-suite, jboss-tools

**I have Spring Tool 4.10 and running on AdoptOpenJDK16 with OpenJ JVM:**

*When I install [JBoss Tools For Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools) I started getting the following error.*

[image]

**1. Download quickstarts list Error:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-05-18 09:35:48.275
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Download quickstarts list".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.model.ProjectExampleUtil.fetchCategories(ProjectExampleUtil.java:396)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.model.ProjectExampleUtil.getCategories(ProjectExampleUtil.java:273)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.model.ProjectExampleUtil.getCategories(ProjectExampleUtil.java:263)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.ProjectExampleXmlProvider.getExamples(ProjectExampleXmlProvider.java:28)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.ProjectExampleManager.getExamples(ProjectExampleManager.java:60)
    at org.jboss.tools.central.editors.GettingStartedHtmlPage$RefreshQuickstartsJob.run(GettingStartedHtmlPage.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.model.ProjectExampleCategoryParser.<clinit>(ProjectExampleCategoryParser.java:38)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception
```

**2. Update project wizard list Error:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-05-18 09:35:46.907
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Update project wizard list".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.FavoriteExampleManager.<init>(FavoriteExampleManager.java:38)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.FavoriteExampleManager.<init>(FavoriteExampleManager.java:31)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.ProjectExamplesActivator.getFavoriteExampleManager(ProjectExamplesActivator.java:1067)
    at org.jboss.tools.central.editors.GettingStartedHtmlPage$5$2.collectFavorites(GettingStartedHtmlPage.java:283)
    at org.jboss.tools.central.editors.GettingStartedHtmlPage$5$2.run(GettingStartedHtmlPage.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.FavoriteItemXmlSerializer.<clinit>(FavoriteItemXmlSerializer.java:46)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create context
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:107)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:565)
    at org.jboss.tools.project.examples.internal.FavoriteItemXmlSerializer.<clinit>(FavoriteItemXmlSerializer.java:44)
    ... 6 more
```

Any help, please. If anyone can tell me how to disable these two, temporarily that would be a great help as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like an issue. you should open a request on our JIRA ( https://issues.redhat.com/projects/JBIDE ) .

It seems that's only related to the central webpage. does it actually crash the tool? all the wizard are available using File>New... menu and downloading the latest quickstart is not mandatory has there is no new content to display as I can see from your screenshot

***edit:*** I reproduce using a java16 VM. it only impacts the central webpage. Can you use another JVM for running JBoss ? I tried with Java11 and Java15 without issues

Comment: Fixed automatically

Answer (score 5):

Just remove "Open on Start up" in Red Hat Central setting (top right of page)